# Combine Workbook - Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different workbooks in same folder path and both workbook has same column headers too.

From A5 to S5, headers and then from A6 i have data in both the workbook

I want to copy one workbook one workbook to other workbook and i have below code:

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()

'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("New Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Export 2")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")

'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
'Offset property moves down 1 row
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)

End Sub
```

I am facing some issue to amend this code as my requirement. (highlighted in red)

1. Workbook Path - I am going to run this macro from other 3rd workbook and have copy and destination workbooks path in their cell in E1 and E2
2. Worksheet Name - I don't know the copy and destination sheet name but data is available on first sheet which name can be anything. (can we amend the sheet name in this macro and then perform our action or what would be best way?)
3. Copy and paste data. help me with the giving range of copy and destination range.

your prompt response will be highly appreciated. help me pls

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still wanting help on this, but...

1. You can get the path of your files like this: `fileName1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E1").Value`
2. First worksheet is always accessible by index (so `Worksheets(1)` is first sheet, `Worksheets(2)` is 2nd, etc). Example: `Set ws1 = Workbooks(fileName1).Worksheets(1)`
3. I think you already have this code (everything that lead you up to): `wsCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)`

I would suggest you turn your `Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()` to something that accepts parameters and where the parameters allow you to control your source and destination more dynamically.